# How to swap out old 4TB drives for new 8TB drives and change from RAID 6 too SHR in a Synology DS1817+?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, synology-diskstation

I'm trying to do two things - replace half of my old, small drives with new, larger drives, and change my RAID type from RAID 6 to SHR.

My NAS is a Synology DS1817+ running DSM 6.2.4. It has eight bays, all full of 4TB drives, in one storage pool, in a RAID 6 array.

I have four new 8TB drives. I want to replace four of my old 4TB drives with the new ones. Once the new drives are in, I want to change RAID 6 to SHR so I can maximize the available space afforded by the new drives. I would like to do all this without losing any data if possible, but I can back up data and start from scratch if necessary.

I have been consulting support docs, but I'm still not sure of the best/fastest/most secure way to go about doing this. For instance: everything I have read says to swap disks one at a time. But if I put in the new disks that way, won't they all get added to the existing storage pool? And if that happens, will I even have the option to create a storage pool running SHR?

Comment: Based on Synology's documentation you cannot convert a storage pool from RAID 6 to a SHR-1/SHR-2 storage pool.  So the simplest solution to that problem would be to install the new drives, create SHR-2 storage pool from those drives, and clone the existing storage RAID 6 pool to the SHR-2 storage pool.  This will allow you to delete the original storage pool after you confirm, all the files are on the new pool.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, didn't realize hitting return would post the comment.  So do these steps sound right? 1) back up all data. 2) power down NAS. 3) remove all disks. 4) install 4 new 8TB disks. 5) turn on NAS. 6) create new SHR storage pool. 7) add in 4 old 4TB disks one at a time, adding them to SHR pool each time.

Comment: @JohnB42 You forgot 2 steps: 5a Re-install DSM using the SynologyAssistant tool. (DSM is installed ON the disks. It needs to be re-installed and you will have to reconfigure everything.) and step 8: Restore your backup.

Comment: @JohnB42 - You can clone data between pools.  Why would you not use that wonderful feature?  My suggestion was 1. Clone the data on the current storage pool to the new storage pool 2. Delete the existing storage pool 3. add the disks to the new storage pool.

Comment: Hi Ramhound. That sounds great, But I don't see how to do it.  I'm currently at 93% capacity with all 8 drives full. If I take out even one disk, let alone 4, I think the old storage pool basically isn't going to exist anymore. Right? Or maybe there's something I'm not aware of?

Comment: Tonny - so if I remove *all* disks and put in the 4 new ones, will I be able to re-install DSM?  The reason I want to remove all the disks is because I have to start a new storage pool.  If I just add one disk at a time, I think I'll stay stuck in one RAID 6 storage pool.